# pyenv failed to load after switching user

Tags: zsh, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ubuntu-20.04, pyenv, zshrc

I follow the installation instruction [here](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#basic-github-checkout), and installed `pyenv` under `/home/mrcai/.pyenv`.

When I log in as `mrcai`, `pyenv` works pretty well as expected; but when I switch to `root` and switch back as `mrcai`, `zsh` shows that it cannot find `pyenv`.

```
/home/mrcai/.zshrc:114: command not found: pyenv
```

And `$PATH` does not contain anything about `.pyenv`, which is not the case under normal situation.

It seems the configuration in `.zshrc` or `.zprofile` did not work well. So could anyone please teach me how to solve this error permanently? Thank you!

Here is my configuration:

1. `/home/mrcai/.zshrc`

```
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
```

2. `/home/mrcai/.zprofile`

```
export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init --path)"
```

- OS: WSL 2 (Ubuntu-20.04) (The same problem also occurs under CentOS 8.5.)
- shell: zsh

Answer (score 0):

Donot install pyenv in this path. Do not install in the "/home" directory, this folder will be isolated when switched to root.

It is recommended to install the softwares in the "/usr/local" directory. It would be a good habit.